# Что значит (a, b) є R?

Tags: математика, множества

[image: отношения]

Что здесь значит (a, b) є R?  Я подумал что каждая пара элементов пренадлежит рациональному числу, но нет так не работает

Comment: какому числу то, если написано что R это подмножество AxB ?

Comment: Тут R это не множество действительных (а не рациональных) чисел, а просто обозначение множества.

Comment: ℝ вот это множество действительных чисел

Comment: Окей есть множество A = {1,2,3}, B = {r, s}, как найти БИНарное отношение этих множеств? В ответе книги там не обьесняеться этот процес но вышло у них, = {(1,r), (1,s), (3,s) } , что за логика? Как тут распределили (уменьшили) это отношение?

Comment: Там же написано, что бинарное отношение - это когда `A = B`.

Comment: Что значит «найти»? Оно не находится, оно задаётся. Какое зададите такое и будет.

Comment: Ну с выше примера что я написал там заданого 3Rs что это значит? А точнее как мы нашли это отношение с тех 2 множест

Comment: Ещё раз: **бинарного** отношения у этих множеств не может быть по определению. Что за отношение у них есть мы можем только гадать т.к. никакой книги у нас нет.

Comment: Это значит, что 3 и s находятся в отношении R. Т. е. пара (3, s) принадлежит отношению. Отношение нельзя найти, вы его сами задаете таким, какое вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Каждая пара принадлежит **отношению**.

Например, у нес есть множества A = { 1, 2, 3} и B = {1, 2, 3}

AxB - множество пар (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3).

Рассмотрим отношение "меньше". Это - множество пар

R = { (1,2), (1,3), (2,3) }

Так понятно? Если (a,b) принадлежит R, то записываем aRb, т.е. a < b :)

Comment: Окей есть множество A = {1,2,3},  B = {r, s}, как найти БИНарное отношение этих множеств? В ответе книги там не обьесняеться этот процес но вышло у них, = {(1,r), (1,s), (3,s) } , что за логика? Как тут распределили (уменьшили) это отношение

Comment: Ну откуда же мне знать, не видя книги и что там написано?...